# How can I use fully_connected layer while looping?

Tags: python, variables, lstm, mdns

I'm making sales forecasting model using seq2seq model and it has 12 time-series. There are 2 functions that one is for train, and another is for test. and then I'd like to use fully connected layer at each time step having same parameters.

this is my code.

```
def mdn_layer(self, lstm_output):
    fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(lstm_output, self.lstm_dim, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, reuse=True)
    fc_mus = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc1, self.num_mixture, reuse=True)
    fc_sigmas = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc1, self.num_mixture, activation_fn=K.exp, reuse=True)
    fc_alphas = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc1, self.num_mixture, activation_fn=tf.softmax, reuse=True)
    return tf.concat((fc_mus, fc_sigmas, fc_alphas), axis=1)

def train_decoder(self):
    # time-batch-dimension
    y_emb_tbd = tf.transpose(self.y_emb, [1, 0, 2])
    y_qty = tf.transpose(self.y[:, :, 10:], [1, 0, 2])
    train_pred = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=self.delay)

    def body(step, state, train_pred):
        mdn_out = self.mdn_layer(state.h)

        train_pred = train_pred.write(step, mdn_out)
        step_qty_layer = self.qty_layer(y_qty[step])

        inp = self.decoder_input_layer(tf.concat((y_emb_tbd[step], step_qty_layer), axis=1))

        next_out, next_state = self.decoder_cell(inp, state)

        return step + 1, next_state, train_pred

    _step, _state, _train_pred = tf.while_loop(
        cond=lambda t, _state, _train_pred: t < self.delay,
        body=body,
        loop_vars=(0, self.init_state, train_pred))

    self.output_train = tf.transpose(_train_pred.stack(), perm=[1, 0])
```

I want to use mdn_layer function in each time step having the same parameters.
however, if I use like it, it would be all the different because I call it every steps. How can I use fully_connected layers in mdn_layer function as only one?

Comment: Do you know those parameters beforehand? Or do you want to stop training those layers at some point during training?

Comment: No It's the first time i want to use it in the loop. I'll iterate the loop 12 times.

Comment: Do you mean weights by "parameters"? What parameters

Comment: yes you're right. parameters mean weights.

Comment: Can you make trainable=False then?